# Android Imageview Logo is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `main_activity.xml` that is displaying a fragmented layout. The layout contains `imageview` (a logo), and some `text fields`. At first, I tried to use `relativelayout`, it looks awesome/perfect on the design view. But when run on the emulater, everything jumble up. So I decided to use a `LinearLayout`. After changing, there's an improvement in the UI. But the problem is the image is not displaying.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="276dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_logob"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="URL"

        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/siteurl"
        android:height="24sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/input_color"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:text=""
    android:hint="Password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:height="24sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/input_color"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="username"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:height="24sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/input_color"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
    android:id="@+id/scannedresult"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scanbtn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scanbtn" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:text="QR Scanner"
        android:id="@+id/scanbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/secretkey"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/secretkey"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secretkey"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/login"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="do_login"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secretkey"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/secretkey"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/secretkey"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:hint="Secret Key"
    android:height="24sp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/secretkey"
    android:background="@color/input_color"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password" />
```

The problem is when i run, it did not display the image logo. What is wrong?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if9Yu.png)

Comment: Did you add "splash_logob" to all drawable folders(drawable-xhdpi, drawable-ldpi etc)?

Comment: use android:src="@drawable/splash_logob" instead of app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_logob"

Comment: Thanks! GUNES - yup i did. AbhayBohra - yeah that seem to be the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
android:src="@drawable/splash_logob"
```

instead of:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_logob"
```

`srcCompat` attribute is defined within `AppCompat` library.

Comment: There's a heroooooooo . You. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your imageview like this

```
<ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView"
         android:layout_width="276dp"
         android:layout_height="276dp"
         android:src="@drawable/splash_logob"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
```